# Multiple word searching in Sql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I've tried to implement code for multiple search with sorting in an SQL query.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `total_ingredients`
  FROM opskrifter as k
     , ingredienser as i
 WHERE k.id = i.opskrifterid 
   AND i.ing_name IN ('salt', 'kommen', 'hakkede tomater', 'pasta', 'stødt chilli')
   GROUP BY k.id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

It works fine when I run the statement in Mysql, but when I try to implement into our php search field, it only uses the first argument that we type.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `total_ingredients`
  FROM opskrifter as k
     , ingredienser as i
 WHERE k.id = i.opskrifterid 
   AND i.ing_name IN ($vals)
   GROUP BY k.id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Where `$vals = "'" . str_replace(",", "', '", $searchquery) . "'"; and $searchsquery = $_POST['search']; //From the searchfield`

Hope you can help me finding whatever I am missing here..

Thanks!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! It's easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid! Wont run on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and unpredictable result in older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh can you give an example? :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to explode `$vals` , and join please follow below code::

```
$vals = explode(',', $searchsquery);
$vals  = join("','", $vals);
$vals = "'$vals'";
```

And put this $val in this query, this will work

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `total_ingredients`
  FROM opskrifter as k
     , ingredienser as i
 WHERE k.id = i.opskrifterid 
   AND i.ing_name IN ($vals)
   GROUP BY k.id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: I get an error when exploding the $vals - 
" Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' "

Comment: @jacobassoignon can please tell me what is in your $val variable comma separated string?

Comment: $vals = " ' " . str_replace(",", "', '", $searchquery) . " ' ";

Comment: and what is in $searchsquery ? give me an example

Comment: $searchquery contains the users input from the search field - Example: 
"salt, pasta, onion" :)

Comment: try $vals = explode(',', $searchsquery);

Comment: This is your example write  ===salt, pasta, onion==== not the double cottation?

Comment: I'm not using double quotation when I search, it was just for you to see the example.

Comment: @jacobassoignon Please see the updated answer. and give feedback

Comment: First remove group by and order by and print the sql query and please send here.

Comment: I have opened a chat room :) !